# How to set automatic transmission password?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, transmission

Hello Guys i need help about transmission password set automatically

Example echo "root password" > settings.json

not good for the shadow file

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

Set password in settings.json is not as bad as you thought. Use this sequence:

- stop transmission.
- set password in settings file. Use `rpc-password` setting
- start app and stop it again.

On last stop app should replace your password by hash. So maybe you dont need to do it dynamic.